# Why Decile values are incorrect using the cut function

Tags: r, dataframe, cut

I tried to attach a decile value for each observation using the code below.However, it seems that the values are not correct. What can be the reason for that?

```
     df<-read.table(text="pregnant glucose blood skin INSULIN MASS  DIAB AGE CLASS  predict_probability 
                                  1     106    70   28     135 34.2 0.142  22     0       0.15316285       
                                  1      91    54   25     100 25.2 0.234  23     0       0.05613959       
                                  4     136    70    0       0 31.2 1.182  22     1       0.54034794       
                                  9     164    78    0       0 32.8 0.148  45     1       0.64361578       
                                  3     173    78   39     185 33.8 0.970  31     1       0.79185196       
                                 11     136    84   35     130 28.3 0.260  42     1       0.31927737       
                                  0     141    84   26       0 32.4 0.433  22     0       0.41609308       
                                  3     106    72    0       0 25.8 0.207  27     0       0.10460090       
                                  9     145    80   46     130 37.9 0.637  40     1       0.67061324       
                                 10     111    70   27       0 27.5 0.141  40     1       0.16152296       
                       ",header=T)

deciles <- cut(df$predict_probability, breaks=c(quantile(df$predict_probability, probs = seq(0, 1, by = 0.10))),labels = 1:10, include.lowest=TRUE)
        df1 <- cbind(df,deciles)
        head(df1,10)
           pregnant glucose blood skin INSULIN MASS  DIAB AGE CLASS predict_probability deciles
        1         1     106    70   28     135 34.2 0.142  22     0          0.15316285       3
        2         1      91    54   25     100 25.2 0.234  23     0          0.05613959       1
        3         4     136    70    0       0 31.2 1.182  22     1          0.54034794       7
        4         9     164    78    0       0 32.8 0.148  45     1          0.64361578       8
        5         3     173    78   39     185 33.8 0.970  31     1          0.79185196      10
        6        11     136    84   35     130 28.3 0.260  42     1          0.31927737       5
        7         0     141    84   26       0 32.4 0.433  22     0          0.41609308       6
        8         3     106    72    0       0 25.8 0.207  27     0          0.10460090       2
        9         9     145    80   46     130 37.9 0.637  40     1          0.67061324       9
        10       10     111    70   27       0 27.5 0.141  40     1          0.16152296       4
```

Comment: When you don't get what you expect you need to tell us what you expect. The code is doing exactly what you asked it to do.  What appears to be wrong to you.

Comment: @Dason, the values of the deciles column are not correct, for example: at first row, the predict_probability  is 0.15316 but the decile value is 3 while it should be 2.

Comment: And why do you think it should be 2

Comment: @Dason, 0-0.1 should be labeled "1",0.1-0.2 should be labeled "2".If you look at the second row, the decile value is correct:predict_probability 0.0561 should be labeled "1" as it is.

Comment: That isn't what you told your code to do though.  If that's what you want then why are you using the quantiles function at all? Just pass seq(0,1,by=0.1) as the breaks parameter directly.  This is why I was telling you that you *need* to specify what you expect. Because your code is doing exactly what you told it to do - it just turns out that your instructions weren't what you intended.

Comment: You should do some debugging on your own to see where this went wrong.  Take a few moments to examine what you're actually passing into the breaks parameter actually is.  Then it might be more clear to you *why* you ended up with the results that you did.

Comment: Thank you @Dason, for the sake of other viewers I'm writing down the line  of code as you proposed, deciles <- cut(df$predict_probability, seq(0,1,by=0.1) ,labels = 1:10, include.lowest=TRUE)

Comment: You can write that as an answer. I'm too lazy to write up a full answer right now but you can do it and eventually it will let you accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Dason's proposal, here is the full answer to the question.
The `quantile` function should be taken out from the code so `seq(0,1,by=0.1)` should be passed directly to the `cut` function.

```
    deciles <- cut(df$predict_probability, seq(0,1,by=0.1) ,labels = 1:10, include.lowest=TRUE)
    df1 <- cbind(df,deciles)
    head(df1,10)
 pregnant glucose blood skin INSULIN MASS  DIAB AGE CLASS predict_probability deciles
1         1     106    70   28     135 34.2 0.142  22     0          0.15316285       2
2         1      91    54   25     100 25.2 0.234  23     0          0.05613959       1
3         4     136    70    0       0 31.2 1.182  22     1          0.54034794       6
4         9     164    78    0       0 32.8 0.148  45     1          0.64361578       7
5         3     173    78   39     185 33.8 0.970  31     1          0.79185196       8
6        11     136    84   35     130 28.3 0.260  42     1          0.31927737       4
7         0     141    84   26       0 32.4 0.433  22     0          0.41609308       5
8         3     106    72    0       0 25.8 0.207  27     0          0.10460090       2
9         9     145    80   46     130 37.9 0.637  40     1          0.67061324       7
10       10     111    70   27       0 27.5 0.141  40     1          0.16152296       2
```